# openCV brightness values meaning of CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, video-capture, brightness

I am wondering how the brightness value in OpenCV works, as I want to have control over it when working with a webcam. What is the scale used by `CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS`?

If I set it to 1, what does that mean? If I set it to 100, what does it mean (for an RGB image)? How is the connection between the two images then? So if I have a RGB pixel with [1, 100, 255] snapped with `cap.set.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, 1`, what would it look like with `cap.set.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, 100`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where supported, the properties are generally forwarded to the backend implementation, so I wouldn't expect there to be much consistency. Which specific VideoCapture backend are you using to access the camera? Which specific camera?

Comment: I am using two systems, one with a Brio 4k another with a logitech C910. I use the cv2.VideoCapture(port) if this is what you mean?

Comment: I mean what's discussed in [this overview](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) selected using [`cv::VideoCaptureAPIs` enum](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d). What platform are you on? That should eliminate options in the case you have to guess.

Comment: e.g. if you're on Windows and it ends up using DirectShow backend, [brightness maps](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/402a77e7f75d33d7711ecee9e85f57fae22199a8/modules/videoio/src/cap_dshow.cpp#L2209) to [`VideoProcAmp_Brightness`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407328(v=vs.85).aspx) | In the V4L backend it maps to `V4L2_CID_BRIGHTNESS`. | Look at the `videoio` source code to find the other cases.

Comment: Thank you for this, I wonder how else I could have learned about this! I'm on it!